# Failed to load driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver from HikariConfig class classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-data-jpa

i'm new to Spring and i'm trying to do a simple project in STS that could access data on a oracle db (created with oracle11g xe) like in this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/#_how_to_complete_this_guide.

Here's my project configuration:

- application properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql:localhost:1521/xe
spring.datasource.username=aiello
spring.datasource.password=123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

- main class:

```
package com.prodotti.crud.products;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ProductsApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProductsApplication.class, args);        
    }
}
```

- Entity class:

```
package com.prodotti.crud.products;

import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODOTTI_AMZ")
public class PRODOTTI_AMZ {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String SKU;

    private String ARTICOLO;
    private String CONDIZIONE;
    private String OFFERTA;
    private int QUANTITA;
    private Date DATA_ORDINE;
    private float PREZZO;
    private float TASSE;
    private String SPEDIZIONE;
    private float TASSA_SPEDIZIONE;
    private float COMMISSIONE;
    private float GUADAGNI;

    public void setSKU(String SKU) {
        this.SKU = SKU;
    }

    public void setARTICOLO(String ARTICOLO) {
        this.ARTICOLO = ARTICOLO;
    }

    public void setCONDIZIONE(String ARTICOLO) {
        this.ARTICOLO = ARTICOLO;
    }

    public void setOFFERTA(String OFFERTA) {
        this.OFFERTA = OFFERTA;
    }

    public void setQUANTITA(int QUANTITA) {
        this.QUANTITA = QUANTITA;
    }

    public void setDATA_ORDINE(Date DATA_ORDINE) {
        this.DATA_ORDINE = DATA_ORDINE;
    }

    public void setPREZZO(float PREZZO) {
        this.PREZZO = PREZZO;
    }

    public void setTASSE(float TASSE) {
        this.TASSE = TASSE;
    }

    public void setTASSA_SPEDIZIONE(float TASSA_SPEDIZIONE) {
        this.TASSA_SPEDIZIONE = TASSA_SPEDIZIONE;
    }

    public void setCOMMISSIONE(float COMMISSIONE) {
        this.COMMISSIONE = COMMISSIONE;
    }

    public void setSPEDIZIONE(String SPEDIZIONE) {
        this.SPEDIZIONE = SPEDIZIONE;
    }

    public void setGUADAGNI(float GUADAGNI) {
        this.GUADAGNI = GUADAGNI;
    }

    public String getARTICOLO() {
        return ARTICOLO;
    }

    public float getCOMMISSIONE() {
        return COMMISSIONE;
    }

    public String getCONDIZIONE() {
        return CONDIZIONE;
    }

    public Date getDATA_ORDINE() {
        return DATA_ORDINE;
    }

    public float getGUADAGNI() {
        return GUADAGNI;
    }

    public String getOFFERTA() {
        return OFFERTA;
    }

    public float getPREZZO() {
        return PREZZO;
    }

    public int getQUANTITA() {
        return QUANTITA;
    }

    public String getSKU() {
        return SKU;
    }

    public String getSPEDIZIONE() {
        return SPEDIZIONE;
    }

    public float getTASSA_SPEDIZIONE() {
        return TASSA_SPEDIZIONE;
    }

    public float getTASSE() {
        return TASSE;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Prodotti_AMZ [SKU=" + SKU + ", Articolo=" + ARTICOLO + ", Condizione=" + CONDIZIONE + ", Offerta=" + OFFERTA  + "]";
    }
}
```

- Repository interface:

```
package com.prodotti.crud.products;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface PROD_AMZ_Repository extends CrudRepository<PRODOTTI_AMZ, Integer> {

}
```

- Controller class:

```
package com.prodotti.crud.products;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller 
@RequestMapping(path="/demo")
public class MainController {
    @Autowired
    private PROD_AMZ_Repository repo;

    @PostMapping("/add")    
    public @ResponseBody String addNewProduct (@RequestParam String SKU, float prezzo) {
        PRODOTTI_AMZ prod = new PRODOTTI_AMZ();
        prod.setSKU(SKU);
        prod.setPREZZO(prezzo);
        repo.save(prod);
        return "Saved";
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/all")
      public @ResponseBody Iterable<PRODOTTI_AMZ> getAllUsers() {
        // This returns a JSON or XML with the users
        return repo.findAll();
      }
}
```

and that's what the console displays when I launch the app:

```
2019-12-17 13:01:18.241 ERROR 80020 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : Failed to load driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver from HikariConfig class classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93
2019-12-17 13:01:18.245 ERROR 80020 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthContributorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthContributorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthContributorAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/prodotti/crud/products/SqlTestConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
2019-12-17 13:01:18.289  INFO 80020 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-12-17 13:01:18.317  WARN 80020 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2019-12-17 13:01:18.337  INFO 80020 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-12-17 13:01:18.370 ERROR 80020 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:156) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.prodotti.crud.products.ProductsApplication.main(ProductsApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:88) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:191) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Anyone?

Comment: If you want to connect to oracle why on earth are you using a MySQL url and driver class to connect? You should use a oracle URL and driver. Even stranger your error is complaining about a Microsoft driver...

Comment: I've changed the properties in : spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe and spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver but still same error

Comment: You can omit the `driver-class-name` property, that is being derived from the URL. Something must be pointing/loading the microsoft driver. Check your configuration/code.